# Redis-Lua array key in string

Tags: lua, redis

I execute Lua under Redis. I face an issue which is that I can't use a string as an array key. 
My coding is like following, and we found that **mytable["wow"]** is discarded:

FileName: hget.lua

```
local mytable = {}
mytable[1]= "Lua"
mytable["wow"] = "Tutorial"
return mytable

Command:redis-cli --eval hget.lua
```

Result returned is:

```
1) "Lua"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You CANNOT have a string key for the table, if you want to return the table to Redis.**

Redis takes the returned table as an array, whose index starting from `1`. It discards other elements of the table whose keys are NOT integers. In your case, i.e. `mytable["wow"] = "Tutorial"`, since the key is a string, Redis ignores this element.

Also, the indexes must be sequential, otherwise, Redis discards some elements. Take the following as an example:

```
local t = {}
t[1] = "1"    -- OK
t[2] = "2"    -- OK
t[4] = "4"    -- since index 3 is missing, this element will be discarded
t["string_key"] = "value"   -- since the key is string, this element will be discarded

return t
```

Result:

```
./redis-cli --eval t.lua 
1) "1"
2) "2"
```